# git reset --hard didn't help me with rake db:migrate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, postgresql, sqlite

When I tried to change my Rails database from Sqlite to Postgres, I ran into problems. Then, I decided to go back to a git commit when everything was working. With:

```
git reset --hard 52ca294cd88de9aaa1c00c95e2cdabd744cd7499
```

I have done `bundle install`. Now when I do `rake db:migrate` I get this message:

> rake aborted!
>   Gem::LoadError: Specified 'postgresql' for database adapter, but the gem is not loaded. Add `gem 'pg'` to your Gemfile (and ensure its version is at the minimum required by ActiveRecord).

I don't understand, at this commit everything was working well in Sqlite3. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe your `config/database.yml` isn't in your checked in your git repo and still configured with postgres. Take a look at that file and change it to sqlite.

Comment: Thanks. I was starting server in my other app that uses pg. That was the problem, I was confused between this two apps.

Answer (score 0):

Please include gem 'pg' in your gemfile and then do bundle as you have changed the adapter you need to include pg gem for postgresql